# Return disclaimer on external links (with href exception)

Tags: jquery, href, external

I have some jQuery code to check all links on the site and return a disclaimer if it is an external link. Works fine. I do NOT want the disclaimer to appear for any embedded youtube videos on the site. I want to alter the code so this happens. So, if link does NOT contain youtube.com, then execute.

This is the original working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  
  $('a').filter(function() { 

     return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;

   })

   .click(function () { 

   var x=window.confirm("You are now leaving our website. Click OK to proceed or cancel to stay on this page."); 

  var val = false;
  if (x)
   val = true;
  else
   val = false;
  return val;

        });   
   
});
```

I'd like to insert the code below code that defines if link is NOT youtube, but I don't know where to put it in the original code. I am new to jQuery. Thank you for any help.

```js
if $('a').not('[href^="//www.youtube"], [href^="https://www.youtube"]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain the `.not()` after your `.filter()`. Also you've got a lot of redundant code in the click confirmation, so I cleaned that up too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('a').filter(function() {  
        return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
    }).not('[href^="//www.youtube"], [href^="https://www.youtube"]').click(function () { 
        return confirm("You are now leaving our website. Click OK to proceed or cancel to stay on this page."); 
    });                 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dave for taking the time to look at this. Your code worked perfect.